# How to make an element smoothly expand itself?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I need the deepest `li>span` text to smoothly expand itself as I'm hovering on the `div` with `li` class.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.kinds {
  width: 600px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.drop_vert_menu {
  text-align: center;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.drop_vert_menu li ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 600px;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #666;
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}

.drop_vert_menu>li {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}

.drop_vert_menu li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

.drop_vert_menu li ul li {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="kinds">
  <ul class="drop_vert_menu">
    <li>
      <div class="li"><span>text that expands</span>
        <ul>
          <li><span>text that should be expanded</span></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use `transition` and `transform` instead of `display: none`

I made a very small adjustment to your existing CSS styles.

Rather than toggling between `display: none;` and `display: block`, I used `opacity` and `transform` to show and hide.

A few notes:

- `transition`: this determines which changes will be animated. In this case, I `transition`ed `opacity` and `transform`. If you prefer, you could use `max-height` to mimic vertical expansion/collapse instead.
- `pointer-events`: this makes sure than the invisible item won't interrupt the cursor hovering/clicking events

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.kinds {
  width: 600px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.drop_vert_menu {
  text-align: center;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.drop_vert_menu li ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 600px;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #666;
  position: relative;
  /* changes are made here */
  transition: transform .2s, opacity .2s;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transform: translateY(-15px);
  /* --------------------- */
}

.drop_vert_menu>li {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}

.drop_vert_menu li:hover ul {
  /* changes are made here */
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
  /* --------------------- */
}

.drop_vert_menu li ul li {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="kinds">
  <ul class="drop_vert_menu">
    <li>
      <div class="li"><span>text that expands</span>
        <ul>
          <li><span>text that should be expanded</span></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```